# Pygame - reset my main loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've been following a series of video tutorials trying to understand pygame, and the code got a bit messy, so I rearranged everything into neat, commented blocks. Unfortunately, when you die, and get the option to "press r to restart", it just doesnt work. After closing, the console pops up with errors for each time I pressed r.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sboe_user\Downloads\Desktop\Python\pygametestin.py", line 104, in <module>
    gameLoop()
  File "C:\Users\sboe_user\Downloads\Desktop\Python\pygametestin.py", line 69, in gameLoop
    gameLoop()
  File "C:\Users\sboe_user\Downloads\Desktop\Python\pygametestin.py", line 69, in gameLoop
    gameLoop()
  File "C:\Users\sboe_user\Downloads\Desktop\Python\pygametestin.py", line 69, in gameLoop
    gameLoop()
  File "C:\Users\sboe_user\Downloads\Desktop\Python\pygametestin.py", line 69, in gameLoop
    gameLoop()
  File "C:\Users\sboe_user\Downloads\Desktop\Python\pygametestin.py", line 69, in gameLoop
    gameLoop()
  File "C:\Users\sboe_user\Downloads\Desktop\Python\pygametestin.py", line 102, in gameLoop
    quit()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site.py", line 362, in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: None
```

I've looked all through the code, and I can't find the problem.
Here's the source code: http://pastebin.com/z2NDfwmj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user presses `r`, you need to reset your gamestate variables i.e. `gameOver = False` and `gameExit = False` (second one not really needed although it helps in clean exit of the game).

```
if event.key == pygame.K_r:
    gameOver = False
    gameExit = False
    reset_vars()
    gameLoop()
```